# Map a folder in depot to another folder in depot

Tags: perforce

I have a bin folder which contains an external compiler. This bin folder is common to 3 projects. Is there a way to point the bin folder to a general bin folder in the depot so I do not duplicate the folder?

Comment: To close-voters: this is *not* off-topic. [It is about a tool (Perforce) commonly used by programmers.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a depot layout something like this:

```
//depot/common/...
//depot/project1/...
//depot/project2/...
//depot/project3/...
```

Check in your compiler under `//depot/common` somewhere and have your clients map the project(s) needed and the common directory.